# jqPlot PieRender number formatting

Tags: jqplot

I am using jqplot.PieRenderer and need my percentages to round to 2 decimal places.  I have formatted the text labels to include a percentage for ADA Compliance, so the users are not solely relying on colors in the legend matching the percentages.  However, my bar chart is rounding to a whole number.

Currently the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [ OMMITTED_PII_IN_CODE ];
    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], 
        { 
            seriesDefaults: {
                // Make this a pie chart.
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                rendererOptions: {
                    // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                    // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                    showDataLabels: true
                }
            }, 

            legend: { 
                show:true, 
                location: 's',
                border: '0px',
                fontSize: '12px',
                // Breaks the ledgend into horizontal.
                rendererOptions: {
                    numberRows: '4',
                    numberColumns: '3'
                }
            }
            ,
            series: [{color:"#000000"}],
            seriesColors: ["#d1ded4","#b8c8bb","#7a9f83","#F4D03F","#337ab7","#ccc","#fcf8e3","#f2dede"],
            title: {
                text: 'WVSOM Contributions Breakdown'
            }


        }
    ); // end plot chart
    }); // end document ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dataLabelFormatString` to specify the format you want the labels in the segments to be. If you define the following within `rendererOptions` it will display to 2 decimal places:

```
dataLabelFormatString: '%#.2f%'
```

`%#.2f` tells it to display to 2 decimal places, and the `%` at the end will display a percent symbol after the number.

You will end up with something like this:

[image: Pie chart with labels to 2 decimal places]

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6a4z9pw/) for a working example